# Ionic iOS Geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic5

I build an app which use geolocation but I do not know how to do the question about to "use the users location for tracking".

I tried to add in config.xml this but nothing happened...

How can I solve this?

Here I also added my pod file. I think it get build new every time as I run the ionic app, or?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>ShareApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Capacitor? Cordova?

Comment: I use this: `
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

Comment: This came up when i try to build and run the app on iOS: 

`[capacitor] [info] Found 2 Cordova plugins for ios:
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-geolocation@4.1.0
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder@3.4.1
[capacitor] ✔ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install in 4.67s
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
[capacitor]        <string>$LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION</string>`

Comment: In browser I got the following error in Console:
`GeolocationPositionError {code: 2, message: "", PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3} `

Comment: Can you please add your `Info.plist` contents?

Comment: It is too long for here :(

Comment: Add it to your original question.

Comment: Thanks I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `Info.plist`, you are not requesting the permissions to access a user's location. The error (and solution) is posted in the console error message you have included.

You need to add the following to your `Info.plist` (modify/remove based on your individual needs):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>
```

This will tell iOS that you would like to access these features and present the user with an option to accept or decline.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works!
I thought I could add these in config.xml and it will generate automatically?

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It's always good practice to check and test without having to rely on external config files to update information.

Comment: Hi @Fabian, I had the same issue. The problem with `config.xml` is that it gets overwritten by the CLI when you sync your files with the iOS/Android app.

Thanks @Super_Simon, for sharing the how-to solution.